# Picture in Picture Disappears Even Though Audio Continues

Tags: swift, avkit, picture-in-picture

I've implemented [picture in picture](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForPictureInPicture.html) with the [`AVPictureInPictureController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontroller) class. It works as long as the application is in focus. From the moment the application is pushed to the background, the picture in picture view fades out and disappears. The audio of the video continues to play in the background.

The application follows Apple's guidelines by enabling the correct background mode and configuring the audio session. The moment the application enters the background, the `pictureInPictureControllerWillStopPictureInPicture(_:)` and `pictureInPictureControllerDidStopPictureInPicture(_:)` delegate methods of the [`AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturecontrollerdelegate) protocol are invoked, indicating that picture in picture is about to be stopped.

There are no logs that point to the root of the problem. Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was caused by the Brightcove SDK. You can find more information on the [Brightcove website](https://support.brightcove.com/picture-picture-native-sdks).